# Computing a cumulative distribution function in Python

Tags: python, statistics

I'm trying to compute the distribution function of any of the usual distributions in Python... However, all the methods I've seen involve first drawing N samples from said distribution, and then order them somehow, and then do a cumulative sum.

In Mathematica, I can just do `CDF[ChiSquaredDistribution[df],quantile]`. If I want another distribution, I just substitute `ChiSquaredDistribution` for the name of that other distribution.

Is there a simple way, like in Mathematica, to compute a cumulative distribution function in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, these can be found in `scipy.stats`. `scipy` has a [long list of different distributions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html) that you can use, both continuous as well as multivariate and discrete. All distribution functions have an underlying `cdf` method which allows you to calculate the cumulative distribution functions of that specific distribution. Using the Chi-squared distribution from your example would look as follows:

```
from scipy.stats import chi2

chi2.cdf(x=30, df=50)
# 0.011164780271550276
```

Using other distributions is as simple as importing that distribution and using the `cdf` method as shown above.

Comment: Thanks Oxbowerce ;)

Comment: By the way, is there a similarly fast way to compute the quantiles of a general distribution? In your link, I only see a way to compute the quantiles given an array... In Mathematica, I can just do 'Quantile[Distribution[df], prob]' .

Comment: I think [`numpy.quantile`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.quantile.html) would be what you're looking for.

Comment: Many thanks...+1. By the way, I'm a bit new to python, and all of this searching between packages to see which has which function is starting to be a bit confusing. What's your opinion, experience in this regard? I'm used to working with Mathematica/R where almost everything comes ready to use...

Comment: Generally doing a quick google search for a specific functionality gives you what you're looking for. Indeed, in R most of these funtions related to statistics are in the standard library because R is more focused on statistics whereas Python is more of a general purpose programming language. I suspect that you can find most of the functions related to statistics in either `numpy` or `scipy`.

Comment: Many thanks for the pointers. ;)